# Is same lexical scoped object retained in block which reference it?

Tags: objective-c, block

I have tested following code.

```
// Employee.h
@interface Employee : NSObject
@end

// Employee.m
@implement Employee
@end

// main.m
int main() {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Employee* john = [[Employee alloc] init];

    void (^print)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"employee = %@", john);
    }

    [john release];
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

I have tracked john's reference count using instrument, but john's reference count doesn't seem to be increased in print block.

I thought john should be captured and retained in print block.

What do I misunderstand?

Comment: sorry, you was not intend to help&encourage for this thread by technically. This thread is one for solving most confused part at Apple Doc and WWDC's contents. In fact, many developers are using block without deep concern. Block detail is just critical as you can look at WWDC.

Answer (score 1):

The block here is a stack-based block. Stack-based blocks do not retain the local context.

`john` will be retained when the block is copied to the heap (by calling `[print copy]`, and do not forget you need to either `release` or `autorelease` the block you copied).

ARC knows when blocks must be copied and released, it will handle that when necessary. You should consider using it, it will make your life a lot easier dealing with blocks.

---

edit

Try this instead:

```
void (^print)(void) = [^{
        NSLog(@"employee = %@", john);
    } copy];

...

[print release];
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! I have read WWDC which says like this"• Blocks have private const copy of stack (auto) variables
■ Object references are retained". my question is john is retained only when print block is copied?

Comment: yes, local variables are retained only when the block is no longer local itself (ie. stack-based). heap-based blocks retain the variables they use, stack-based blocks don't. With ARC, you must assume every block is heap-based (even when obviously not) and be careful with retain cycles. Google `weakself block` for more info.